# Java EE application and red5 server integration

Tags: jakarta-ee, integration, red5

I have an existing Java EE application(spring+hibernate). I want to add video record/streaming functionality to it. I want to use Red5. 
How can i integrate the Red5 to existing application(Which is also running on tomcat). 
(Note: Authentication is done on existing app)

Answer (score 0):

Red5 is basically a modified Apache Tomcat server and Red5 is also using Spring.
Instead of merging Red5 functionality into your app, it might be easier to merge you application into the Red5 Application Server and use that as Servlet Container.
You can also compile Red5 to Jetty if you don't like Tomcat.
If you are using JBoss or other Application servers and need to merge Red5 to your application it will be more difficult.
However you *can* compile Red5 to a .war package and deploy that to JBoss.
But there is no official release of the Red5 .war package and what bugs might exist in that .war is also not published or documentated.
I think there is an ANT task target to compile the .war package if you checkout the project from googlecode.

Sebastian

Comment: @Sebastian : In my case, I am using Red5 just for delivery and streaming. The other process like upload, encode is done by different application (different stack). How do I integrate Red5 into my stack.

Comment: you might try the .war version. However you will need to study some of the Red5 configurations to have an idea where to place the files for streaming and how to access them.

Comment: @Sebastian : Thank you for the suggestions.
Since the existing application is already on production, its  difficult to move the entire app on red5. We have decided to keep red5 on a seperate server
The problem we are facing is how to identify whether the user is authenticated or not on Red5?(The auth part is handled in existing application). Any suggestions on this?

Comment: You have to look at the http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/trunk/src/org/red5/server/adapter/ApplicationAdapter.java every red5 webapp implements this class. It contains specific event handlers that are called whenever a client connects, requests a file et cetera. You should implement your authentication into that class, every time a client connects you identify him, otherwise you drop the connection. There is also a possibility to pass parameters in the connect method of the RTMP-Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download "Red5War_1.0" or latest version.

Step 2: Un-Zip the Red5War_1.0.war

Step 3: Copy the content of "/WEB-INF/classes" of inflated war folder and paste it in "Source Packages".

Step 4: Navigate to "/WEB-INF/lib" of inflated war folder, select all the dependency jars and Paste it to your "Library" Folder.

Step 5: copy the content of WEB-INF/web.xml of to your web.xml of your project.

Step 6: Copy the remaining content ("other than /META-INF, /WEB-INF/classes" and "/WEB-INF/lib") of the inflated folder to "Web Folder" of your Project.

Step 7: Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080

Please advise, if any change in procedure is required.

Arumugam A.V